# hive sql select count(*) generate too big job.jar file

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to hadoop and hive. I have configured them successfully(maybe...) on four servers. I can run the wordcount example from hadoop. Then I create a table in hive, with just 5 records to test. But when I submit select count(*) from the table, it takes about 2-3 minutes(may be longer) before submitting the mr job:

(this is message from the console) .

```
Query ID = root_20181215204727_4ffb47f7-022f-4661-8b46-fa1eb1d00d65 .   
Total jobs = 1 .   
Launching Job 1 out of 1 .   
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1 .   
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):    
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number> .   
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:    
set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number> .   
In order to set a constant number of reducers:    
set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number> .
```

That's what i get in the first two minutes.

And after that I can see the job being submitted from 8088 web ui.
That's the message from the console:

```
Starting Job = job_1544796522138_0016, Tracking URL = 
http://aa:8088/proxy/application_1544796522138_0016/
Kill Command = /usr/local/hadoop-2.9.2/bin/hadoop job  -kill 
job_1544796522138_0016
```

But it takes about 15 minutes to finish. It stucks in the map %0 , reduce 0% for a long time.

```
2018-12-15 20:56:37,106 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2018-12-15 20:57:37,560 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
```

I have looked the log and check the tmp dir from hdfs and see that the job.jar file generated by hive is 34MB, which takes a lot of time to share between nodes(I think...). So why the jar file is so big??? Do I include something that is not necessary? Or do I make some mistakings when configuring? I think I make a very simple configuration.

Now the select finished...

```
hive> use test;
OK
Time taken: 0.157 seconds
 hive> select count(*) from mrtest;
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in 
the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. 
spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Query ID = root_20181215204727_4ffb47f7-022f-4661-8b46-fa1eb1d00d65
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1544796522138_0016, Tracking URL = 
http://aa:8088/proxy/application_1544796522138_0016/
Kill Command = /usr/local/hadoop-2.9.2/bin/hadoop job  -kill 
job_1544796522138_0016
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of 
reducers: 1
2018-12-15 20:56:37,106 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2018-12-15 20:57:37,560 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2018-12-15 20:58:37,708 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2018-12-15 20:59:37,793 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2018-12-15 21:00:37,818 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2018-12-15 21:01:10,431 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative 
CPU 1.71 sec
2018-12-15 21:01:19,614 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative 
CPU 3.74 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 3 seconds 740 msec
Ended Job = job_1544796522138_0016
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 3.74 sec   HDFS 
Read: 
7375 HDFS Write: 101 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 3 seconds 740 msec
OK
5
Time taken: 842.183 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```